How do I load the github file into my application that Ii created using the Django framework?
I am creating a program that will be able to get all repositories in a GitHub account of a specific logged-in user. I successfully authenticate the user, but the problem is, how could I get the repositories of the authenticated user? The code below has full details on how I did it, but I
still can't get the repositories. Also for the endpoint link, what shall I add there?
This view fetches repositories of the authenticated user from GitHub
Retrieve the access token from the session after OAuth authentication
def github_repositories(request):
access_token = request.session.get('github_access_token')

    # Check if the access token exists
    if access_token:
        # Set up the headers for GitHub API request
        headers = {
            'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
            'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3+json'
        }
        
        # Make a GET request to GitHub API to fetch user repositories
        response = requests.get('  https://api.github.com/orgs/ORG/repos', headers=headers)
        
        # Check the response status code
        if response.status_code == 200:
            # Parse the JSON response to extract repositories
            repositories = response.json()
            # Pass repositories to the template
            return render(request, 'dashboard.html', {'repositories': repositories})
        else:
            # Handle API request errors
            return HttpResponse('Error fetching repositories', status=response.status_code)
    else:
        # Redirect the user to log in with GitHub if the access token is not found
        return redirect('github_login')

I am awaiting solutions and responses from you. You may email me at dadyoo360@gmail.com

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
